# Newts what am I riddle?

Tags: riddle, word

What am I?

> Natural face
>   Elegant kings cape
>   Wicked rows of gnashers
>   Terrible tendrils fire like arrows
>   Soft croon fades to black

Hint 1 -

> Newts more like "*Newt S.' what am I riddle?*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Manticore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manticore)

Natural face

> The manticore has a human-like head

Elegant kings cape

> I think this refers to the lion's mane (as the lion is the "King of the Jungle")

Wicked rows of gnashers

> The manticore has very sharp teeth.

Terrible tendrils fire like arrows

> The manticore has a tail of venomous spines similar to porcupine quills.

Soft croon fades to black

> In the world of Harry Potter, the manticore is reputed to croon softly to its victims as it devours them.

Hint

> Newton Scamander (*Newt S*) is the main character from Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, which features the manticore.

Comment: 100% correct! Nice job